# Question on display resolution macbook air 2010

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, resolution

My 2010 MacBook Air shows a max display resolution of 1440 x 900.
If I attach to a display like the Apple 27" with 2560-by-1440-pixel resolution, will i be limited to the what the macbook air can put out?

I never understood if this is a video card limitation or a display limitation.

I am looking to get more on a screen, not just bigger that I see on the MBA.

Also, should i be looking for a monitor that is displayport or mini displayport since this is what I have or should i not worry since I can use a mini displayport to hdmi or dvi adaptor?

PS, I also have a Lenovo that has displayport out on it that I will use the new display on too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macbook can output to the apple display at full resolution supported by that display with the extended desktop preference set in system preferences. If you set the mirror desktop preference in system preferences, the resolution will change on the external display to match your macbook.

I have a dell monitor with display port out and bought a display port to mini display port cable and it works great. There are adapters for basically any conversion, but I suggest a monitor with display port or mini display port because it supports higher resolutions, and it's the future obviously.